# How to use 'like' in Anorm query?

Tags: scala, anorm

My Data base is porstgres, and I am trying to write a query that will use like or ~ (postgres regex). 
I couldn't write this query using on.

so here is what I tried to write:

```
SQL(s"""SELECT id, name
       |FROM my_table 
       |WHERE name ~ '^{name}'""")
.on('name -> name).as(parser.*)
```

Or:

```
SQL(s"""SELECT id, name
       |FROM my_table 
       |WHERE name like '{name}%'""")
.on('name -> name).as(parser.*)
```

The code that is working for me does not use on.
And it looks like this:

```
SQL(s"""SELECT id, name
       |FROM my_table 
       |WHERE name """.concat(s"like '$name%'").as(parser.*)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When having a `... '{param}'` with a string value passed using `.on`, the JDBC statement is prepared as `... ''$strVal''`, as the value is escaped according JDBC.

So the the single quotes should be removed from the SQL statement, and the `%`, must be part of the escaped string value.

```
SQL("""SELECT id, name
   |FROM my_table 
   |WHERE name like {name}""")
  .on('name -> s"{name}%").as(parser.*)
```

Moreover, there the String Interpolation is useless (`SQL(s"...")` should be `SQL("...")`), as Anorm placeholder are not prepared using that.

If you want to use interpolation, it would be better to use Anorm one.

```
SQL"""SELECT id, name
   |FROM my_table 
   |WHERE name like ${name + "%"}""".
  as(parser.*)
```

Comment: In case anyone had difficulty telling the difference between the two. cchantep's second example uses the variable `name` if it's in scope. Some (including me) prefer to directly dictate the interpolation variables with `on`, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: in your first snippet did you by any chance mean `'name -> s"$name%"`?

Comment: No, `s"..."` is String interpolation, not Anorm parameter interpolation

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you're trying to pass a parameter to inside of a string.

What I mean is that instead of `WHERE name like '{name}%'` it should be just `WHERE name like {name}`.

```
SQL(s"""SELECT id, name
       |FROM my_table 
       |WHERE name like {name}""")
.on('name -> "foo%").as(parser.*)
```